# SQL query for paging received records

Tags: c#, sql, paging, npoco

I want to write a query that receives informations about customers and their orders from another table and show them in this way:

```
Customer 1
 Customer 1 Order 1
 Customer 1 Order 2
Customer 2
 Order 1 Customer 2
Customer 3
 Order 1 Customer 3
....
```

And I want to do paging by Customers. For example - if I define items per page = 10, I want to show 10 customers, no matter how many orders they had.

I prepared this query but I think it's not gonna work properly and I don't know how to solve this..

```
var result = db.Page<Customer>(pageNumber, 10, "SELECT c.*, o.* FROM Customers c JOIN Orders o 
ON o.Id = c.Id");
```

Comment: No .NET class has a `Page<T>` method. You used some third party library. which one? Have you encountered a problem?

Comment: I used NPoco method for this

Comment: May I suggest you edit your question to add the [tag:NPoco] tag, so your question is seen by people with the relevant expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()` and filter on that:

```
SELECT c.*, o.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY c.id) as seqnum
FROM Customers c JOIN 
     Orders o 
     ON o.Customer_Id = c.Id;
```

You need to use `WHERE` for filtering, rather than `LIMIT` or `FETCH` or whatever.

Comment: The OP is using a pager class that's probably going to wrap this in `TOP 10` or use `OFFSET ... FETCH NEXT..`

Comment: Yes, but I want to do the paging by Customers, no by all Orders. That's my main trobule. So I want to retrieve at one time all orders of specified 10 customers depending on which page am I

Comment: Sorry, I meant "o.Customer_Id = c.Id"

Comment: @GordonLinoff so if I execute this query, I receive records where same customers have same seqnum, so how do I paginate by this seqnum now?